# How can i set codeigniter sessions to globally accessible?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I am storing `userid` in session user data, but the user data is only available in one controller. I want to make the CodeIgniter sessions globally accessible.

I have this code

```
$custom_data = array(
            'userid'    =>  $user_id,
            'loggedin'  =>  TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($custom_data);
```

I just loaded session library, and I have also used some hacks after searching around, but nothing is working the way I would like. How can I tackle this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hang on, there's nothing about using sessions in CodeIgniter anywhere on the internet?

This framework HAS been out for 5 years so I doubt that's the case. Maybe you've not described your problem very well?

By globally accessable if you mean you want to get it in other controllers then use:

```
$this->session->userdata('userid');
```

That will return your value.

If by globally available you mean you want it available in other PHP files (not CodeIgniter) then thats a totally different thing. You need to use native PHP sessions to work natively with PHP and CodeIgniter sessions to work with CodeIgniter sessions. Simple! :)

Comment: I set the userdata to 'userid' and then load a view in that view i put `print_r($this->session->userdata);` it print out everythin also userid but when i navigate to another view loading from another controller, the userid field in session use data is empty

Comment: You simply repeat the $this->session->userdata('userid');
wherever you need it. Its always globally accessible.  I use it right in the view

Comment: "if ( $this->session->userdata('name') ){
        echo "Welcome " . $this->session->userdata('name'); (Or user id)

Comment: Bilal, I didn't say use `$this->session->userdata` as that is a property not a function. I said use: `$this->session->userdata('userid');`